# Determining the (opened) filename from a FILE *

Tags: c, stdio

Given a stdio `FILE *` pointer, is there a method by which I can discover the name of the (opened) file?

Comment: A file descriptor is an integer, which is different from a FILE*. I'm assuming you want the answer in terms of FILE*, but you may want to edit your title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks (from [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2008-09/msg00751.html)) that on POSIX systems you can use fileno() to get the file descriptor from a FILE*, then use fstat to get the stat info from the file descriptor. The stat structure contains the device number and inode number. You can check the filesystem for files which match the inode. This will obviously take some time for a filesystem full of stuff.

The reason that this isn't really possible (as explained in the linked article) is that a stream can have no filename if it's something like stdin or stdout, or if it's an open file that has been deleted. It can have multiple names because of hardlinks as well.

The linked article mentions [this comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.it.usyd.edu.au/~dasymond/mirror/c-faq/osdep/fdfilename.html) which outlines the insolubility of this problem in brief.

EDIT: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for more than just the "no you can't" answer.

Comment: fstat() is used to describe the file that the file descriptor has open.  You use fileno() to get the file descriptor from the file pointer.  Note that the inode might not be found, or there might be multiple possible names for the file (depending on the number of hard links).

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Apart from anything else, the FILE * may not refer to a named file. If your application needs this facility, you wil need to maintain some kind of map 
from open FILE *s to the file name you used to open them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard defined portable solution. However, you can take a look at your OS provided API set. POSIX systems have a `fstat` function that takes a descriptor (not a `FILE *`) and returns some information.