# How get fileName having FILE*?

Tags: c++, c

In my class I have `FILE* ascii_file;` data member, which always is initialized via class constructor. How can I get full path of the `asci_file`? I don't want to store more information about the file expect `ascii_file`, and want it to work on windows, linux and solaris.

Comment: Any reason that you can't add a filename param to the ctor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)

Comment: Same as this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831004/determining-the-opened-filename-from-a-file

Comment: @Svisstack/@Matt Kane - this is not a dup, each q has only Linux-specific responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This task is going to require non-portable code.

On Windows you can convert `FILE*` to CRT file descriptor using [_fileno](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx), and then convert to an OS handle using [_get_osfhandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6.aspx).

Then you can get the filename as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789%28VS.85%29.aspx) (using file mapping).

> Obtaining a File Name From a File
>   Handle

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution for Linux:

[Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)