# Is it possible in java to know the output files specified when executing a jar?

Tags: java, file, output

**English :**
Is it possible in java to know the output files specified when executing a jar (without parsing parameters) ? For example with this command :

```
java -jar application.jar 1> output.log 2> error.err
```

Java can know the default output is in output.log and error in error.err ?

**Français :**
Est-il possible en java de connaitre les fichiers de sorties spécifiés lors de l'éxécution d'un jar (sans parser les arguments) ?

Par exemple dans le cas de l'éxecution de cette commande :

```
java -jar application.jar 1> output.log 2> error.err
```

Comment: do you want to know the name of output.log and error.err file names in your Main() method??

Comment: The only ways I can think of are all platform-specific and/or involve JNI.  And even those can be unreliable.  For starters, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221186/how-do-i-find-a-filename-given-a-file-pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are redirecting output to files is done at operating system level but not on java level, so its not possible the way you are doing.

**[Alernate way]**

The only way it is possible if you explicitly send the the file name as java arg to the program and change the system output stream manually.

Run Command

```
java -jar application.jar output.log error.err
```

Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  // file names will be available as args[1] and args2[]
  String outputFileName = args[1];
  String errorOutputFileName = args[2];
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(args[1]))));
  System.setErr(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(args[2]))));
  // ...

}
```

Comment: Ok so I will parse the parameters of application to find them ... Thanks!