# Get file name from FILE * returned from mkstemp

Tags: c, file

I have some code that looks like this:

```
char template[] = "temp-XXXXXX";
FILE * f = mkstmp(template);

/* ... some stuff is written to f with fprintf ...*/

char fname[15] = xyzzy(f); // <-- Problem

char tmp[20];
sprintf(tmp,"less %s", fname);
system(tmp);
```

I need to find out the name given to `f` by `mkstmp` so I can call `less` on it.

Comment: I think you should self answer your question, so if someone finds your question in the future, ho would also find the answer (and maybe you would earn some rep :-) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain filename from file pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937645/obtain-filename-from-file-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @ebyrob not quite, because while in the general case it's not possible (in a portable way at least), in the special case of using `mkstmp()` it's easy

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Yep, did that.

Comment: No, `mkstemp` (not `mkstmp`) returns an `int`. I don't know of *any* library function that returns a `FILE`.

Comment: @KeithThompson from the mkstemp man page: "On  success,  these  functions return the file descriptor of the temporary file.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."

Comment: @Blacksilver File descriptors are integers. Read `man 2 open`, `man 2 write`.

Comment: @Blacksilver: And if you need a `FILE*`, you can pass the file descriptor to `fdopen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template` will have been changed to the file's name. So:

```
sprintf(tmp,"less %s",template)
system(tmp);
```

Comment: You should place your answer here and accept that. Do not place the answer in your question.

Comment: @rob This is here for the benefit of people who scroll right past the question.